# I got Google SMTPAuthenticationError when I send email via django with NON-gmail smtp server, even though I don't use smtp.gmail.com

Tags: django, dns, smtp, google-workspace

I'm running a website made with django. This website has a contact form, and when you submit, you and administrator will receive an email.

```py
message = render_to_string('email/contact_us_message.txt', context)
send_async_mail.delay(_('subject'), message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [contact.email])
message_for_admin = render_to_string('email/contact_us_message_for_admin.txt', context)
send_async_mail.delay(_('subject'), message_for_admin, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [settings.ADMIN_EMAIL])
```

I used to subscribe to gsuite and use that smtp server. There was no problem sending and receiving emails.

I decided to use another email hosting service two days ago, so I modified my dns record, canceled gsuite and deleted my account.

The new email hosting service worked fine in the local environment. However, in production, email can't be sent sometimes. When I check the task results of celery results, it says 535, "b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." I understand that this error message is displayed when connecting to the google service. For example, the app password is not set. But I don't use smtp.gmail.com or services related to google anymore.

```
EMAIL_URL=smtp+tls://no-reply@mydomain.com:password@new-smtp-server.com:587
```

so I don't understand why I get this error message. Since I changed the dns record and it's been a little while, do I get this error related smtp.gmail.com? If I wait and the dns cache will be updated, will the error disappear?

Comment: have you restarted celery workers after changing email setting?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's still showing same error.

Answer (score 1):

If email is working in local environment and thoroughgoing error on server then first you need to **Turn ON** the [less secure app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on your email account. Second you need to verify that it was you who is sending email from server not some malicious user.

Comment: I don't use gmail or gsuite for sending email.